# Bit Operation in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am new in C and this is for a school project. I am implementing the Skinny Block Cipher in C.

My code:

```
            unsigned char *bits[8]; // this array holds 1 byte of data.
            ... call in another func to convert hex to bit.

            unsigned int four = bits[4] - '0'; // value 0
            unsigned int seven = bits[7] - '0'; // value 1
            unsigned int six = bits[6] - '0'; // value 1

            four = four ^ ~(seven | six); // eq 1;
```

Now, my question

1. Do I have to convert the char to int every time to run the bit operation? What will happen if I do it using unsigned char?

If I store the value for eq - 1 on an unsigned int, the value is `fe` which is wrong (according to an online bit calculator), on the other hand, if I store the result in an unsigned char, the value is -2 which is correct. What's the difference? I am kind of lost here.

2. bits[8] is a pointer and I tried to do the eq 1 using indexes from bits pointer, like bits[4], etc but my VSCode throws an error and I don't understand why. Obviously, I have some gaps in my knowledge. I am using my Python knowledge to go through this.

I don't know if I am giving all the information that's needed. Hit me up for extras!

TIA.

---

I updated the code

```
unsigned char bits[9];
```

It converts `a3` into `010100011`.

Comment: bits[8] is not a pointer. It's an array of 8 pointers, which is probably not what you want. unsigned char bits[8] would make more sense. But you've not shown enough code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         unsigned char *bits[8]; // this array holds 1 byte of data.
> ```

No, it is an array of 8 pointers to char.

> `unsigned int four = bits[4] - '0'; // value 0`

This will not work as you subtract the integer `'0'` from the pointer.

If you want to keep the string representation of the number in the binary form you need to define an array of 9 chars

```
char bits[9] = "10010110";
```

Then you can do the operations as in your code.

> Do I have to convert the char to int every time to run the bit
> operation? What will happen if I do it using unsigned char?

If you want to keep it as a string then - yes.

```
unsigned char x = 0x96;

unsigned int four = !!(x & (1 << 4)); 
unsigned int seven = !!(x & (1 << 7));
unsigned int six = !!(x & (1 << 6));
```

Comment: Is it really a string when the type of the array is `unsigned char`?

Comment: `char` can be unsigned or signed depending on the implementation

Comment: What if I don't want to keep it in string? basically I am trying to AES operations here, so there's lot of bit manipulation involved in every step. What's the easiest way to do something like this? 

I was thinking of converting the 128 bit hex (from input) into binary and working on that. @0___________

Comment: @0___________ That's not what I'm asking. I know that `char` can be either `signed` or not. Is `unsigned char` a valid string type? I doubt it is, that's why I ask.

Comment: @marco-a IMO it is

Comment: @O_o then you need to lean bit operations